# MySQL multiple if statements

Tags: mysql, nested

I have a problem with MySQL query. I have a big query that selects from multiple tables and it works just fine. I would like to edit one small part of it.

This is the small part that I want to edit. This part works fine but I would like to add another if statement to it.

```
round(if(m.id in (2280659, 2300116,3612005, 5309555), m.duration / 100, m.duration) / 60,1) as "Activity time in minutes"
```

I would like it to be something like this but I can't seem to get the syntax right. I tried a **nested if** example I found on the internet but this gives me syntax error.

```
round(if(m.id in (2280659, 2300116,3612005, 5309555), m.duration / 100, m.duration, if m.id in (12312323, 2323232), m.duration / 1000, m.duration)) / 60,1) as "Activity time in minutes"
```

I want **m.duartion / 100** if m.id in (2280659, 2300116,3612005, 5309555) and I want **m.duration / 1000** if m.id in (12312323, 2323232)

I hope I was being clear enough. I would appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction, thank you!

EDIT 1:
Changed the query to match the bracket count but still no success.

```
round(if(m.id in (2280659, 2300116,3612005, 5309555), m.duration / 100, m.duration, if (m.id in (12312323, 2323232), m.duration / 1000, m.duration)) / 60,1) as "Activity time in minutes"
```

Error message:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'if(m.id in (12312323, 2323232), m.duration / 10000, m.duration)) / 60,1) as "Tegevuse kest' at line 3

Comment: You haven't nested your if's look at them more carefully and where the `,`'s are

Comment: *I tried a nested if example I found on the internet but this gives me syntax error.* Show the error message. I doubt it is relative to nesting. Simply count the amount of left and right parenthesis...

Comment: @Akina com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'if(m.id in (12312323, 2323232), m.duration / 10000, m.duration)) / 60,1) as "Tegevuse kest' at line 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IF() construct is

```
IF( condition is true, use this answer, else this answer)
```

To nest as you are trying, you need

```
IF( condition, this, IF( second condition, this, else default ) )
```

You can also do with a case/when which might make it easier to follow

```
round( case when m.id in (2280659, 2300116,3612005, 5309555)
               then m.duration / 100
            when m.id in (12312323, 2323232)
               then m.duration / 1000
            else m.duration end
     / 60,  1) as "Activity time in minutes"
```

Comment: With case/when it seems to be a lot simpler indeed. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> EDIT 1: Changed the query to match the bracket count but still no success.

After pretty formatting the problem becomes visible:

```
round( 
       if( 
           m.id in (
                     2280659, 2300116,3612005, 5309555
                   ), 
           m.duration / 100, 
           m.duration, 
           if( 
               m.id in (
                         12312323, 2323232
                       ), 
               m.duration / 1000, 
               m.duration
             )
     ) / 60, 1
) as "Activity time in minutes"
```

1. Outer IF() have 4 arguments
2. Final closing parenthesis have no matching opening one.